# Is there any php function that wait untill aws lightsail instance state is running?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-lightsail

I have used this code to create aws lightsail instance using php code.

```
$client->createInstances([
        'addOns' => [
            [
                'addOnType' => 'AutoSnapshot',
                'autoSnapshotAddOnRequest' => [
                    'snapshotTimeOfDay' => config('aws.snapshotTime'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'availabilityZone' => config('aws.instanceAvailabilityZone'),
        'blueprintId' => config('aws.os'),
        'bundleId' => config('aws.instanceType'),
        'instanceNames' => ['testinstance],
        'userData' => config('aws.afterInstallScript'),
    ]);
   return $result = $client->getInstanceState([
        'instanceName' => $instanceName
    ]);
```

The code is executed with instance state pending. But my requirement is that it should return when the instance state is running. Aws SDK has waitUntil() function but I don't know how to use this in lightsail.

Can anyone help me with this?